# android Json Volley how to create interface

Tags: android, json, android-volley

**How to create interface get only Response and set Adapter **

*I have lots of json create single method pass url get response handle Error network Check*

```
    public void getJsonRequest(String url){//interface
  JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                list =parseJSONRequest(response);// create interface
               adapter.setAllLinks(list);  // create interface
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                errorJson.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String map = VolleyErrorException.getErrror(error, getContext());
                errorJson.setText(map);
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can make an interface like this :

```
public interface resultInterface {

    void Success(JSONObject response);

    void Error(VolleyError error);
}
```

In the mainActivity , implement resultInterface . In the getJson() method, add another parameter like this:

```
public void getJsonRequest(String url, final resultInterface listener){
  JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                listener.Success(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                listener.Error(error);
            }
        });}
```

From your mainActivity, when call the getJsonRequest as follows:

```
  getJsonRequest(url,this);
```

This will enable callbacks to your main activity.You should receive the Success and Error callbacks now.
Hope this helps!

Comment: public class CompanyBuzzFragment extends Fragment  implements getJsonRequest { } and pass parameter url;         void Success(JSONObject response);

    void Error(VolleyError error);  void onUrl()

Comment: `public class CompanyBuzzFragment extends Fragment implements resultInterface { } `
 This should be the line.. the getJsonRequest() is the method and not the interface.. Also when you call the getJsonRequest from companyBuzzFragment, do this :   `getJsonRequest(url,this);`    This will set the interface

Comment: Thanks i have a one more question Json Api limit="10"&offset="0" =>RecyclerView      Adapter   one time show screen limit=10&offset=0 and scroll show data limit="10"&offset="10"  pagination Fetch more data please Help me

Comment: What exactly is your question? It will be easier if you mark this question as answered and start a new question for that. That way more people will be able to help you out

Comment: Hey, just following up on whether your problem was resolved.. Didn't see a reply from your side

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example done in Kotlin

You can also create one like this

```
interface IVolley {

    fun onResponse(response: String)
 }
```

Creating requests and adding it to queue, then just call the methods and handle in MainActivity

```
 class MyVolleyRequest 

        private var mRequestQueue: RequestQueue?=null
        private var context: Context?=null
        private var iVolley: IVolley?=null
        var imageLoader: ImageLoader?=null
            private set



        val requestQueue: RequestQueue
        get(){
            if(mRequestQueue == null)
                mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context!!.applicationContext)
            return mRequestQueue!!
        }

        private constructor(context: Context, iVolley: IVolley)
        {
            this.context = context
            this.iVolley = iVolley
            mRequestQueue = requestQueue
            this.imageLoader = ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,object: ImageLoader.ImageCache{
                private val mCache = LruCache<String, Bitmap>(10)
                override fun getBitmap(url: String?): Bitmap? {
                    return mCache.get(url!!)
                }

                override fun putBitmap(url: String?, bitmap: Bitmap?) {
                    mCache.put(url!!,bitmap!!)
                }

            })
        }

        internal constructor(context: Context)
        {
            this.context = context
            mRequestQueue = requestQueue
            this.imageLoader = ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,object: ImageLoader.ImageCache{
                private val mCache = LruCache<String, Bitmap>(10)
                override fun getBitmap(url: String?): Bitmap? {
                    return mCache.get(url!!)
                }

                override fun putBitmap(url: String?, bitmap: Bitmap?) {
                    mCache.put(url!!,bitmap!!)
                }

            })
        }

        fun <T> addToRequestQueue(req: Request<T>){
            requestQueue.add(req)
        }


        // GET METHOD
        fun getRequest(url:String)
        {
            val getRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, null, Response.Listener { response ->
                iVolley!!.onResponse(response.toString())
            },Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                iVolley!!.onResponse(error.message!!)
            })

            addToRequestQueue(getRequest)
        }

        // POST method with params
        fun postRequest(url:String)
        {
            val postRequest = object:StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,
                Response.Listener { response ->
                    iVolley!!.onResponse(response.toString ())
                },Response.ErrorListener {error -> iVolley!!.onResponse((error.message!!)) })
            {
                override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                    val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                    params["name"] = "Assad Ginem"
                    params["value"] = "This value is Put from Android App"
                    return params
                }
            }
                addToRequestQueue(postRequest)
        }

        // PUT method with params
        fun putRequest(url:String)
        {
            val postRequest = object:StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT,url,
                Response.Listener { response ->
                    iVolley!!.onResponse(response.toString ())
                },Response.ErrorListener {error ->  iVolley!!.onResponse((error.message!!)) })
            {
                override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                    val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                    params["name"] = "Assad Ginem"
                    params["value"] = "This is value posted from Android App"
                    return params
                }
            }
            addToRequestQueue(postRequest)
        }

        // PATCH method with params
        fun patchRequest(url:String)
        {
            val postRequest = object:StringRequest(Request.Method.PATCH,url,
                Response.Listener { response ->
                    iVolley!!.onResponse(response.toString ())
                },Response.ErrorListener {error ->   iVolley!!.onResponse((error.message!!))})
            {
                override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                    val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                    params["name"] = "Assad Ginem"
                    params["value"] = "This is value patch from Android App"
                    return params
                }
            }
            addToRequestQueue(postRequest)
        }

        // DELETE method with params
        fun deleteRequest(url:String)
        {
            val deleteRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.DELETE, url, Response.Listener { response ->
                iVolley!!.onResponse(response)
                },Response.ErrorListener { error -> iVolley!!.onResponse(error.message!!)
            })

            addToRequestQueue(deleteRequest)
        }

        companion object{
            private var mInstance: MyVolleyRequest? = null

            @Synchronized
            fun getInstance(context: Context, iVolley: IVolley): MyVolleyRequest{
                if(mInstance == null)
                {
                    mInstance = MyVolleyRequest(context,iVolley)
                }
                return mInstance!!
            }
        }
```

MainActivity.kt

```
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), IVolley {
        override fun onResponse(response: String) {
            //Show

   Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,""+response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            btn_get.setOnClickListener {
                MyVolleyRequest.getInstance(this@MainActivity, this@MainActivity)
                    .getRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
            }

            btn_post.setOnClickListener {
                MyVolleyRequest.getInstance(this@MainActivity, this@MainActivity)
                    .postRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
            }

            btn_put.setOnClickListener {
                MyVolleyRequest.getInstance(this@MainActivity, this@MainActivity)
                    .putRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
            }

            btn_patch.setOnClickListener {
                MyVolleyRequest.getInstance(this@MainActivity, this@MainActivity)
                    .patchRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
            }

            btn_delete.setOnClickListener {
                MyVolleyRequest.getInstance(this@MainActivity, this@MainActivity)
                    .deleteRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
            }

            btn_image_loader.setOnClickListener {
                image_view.setImageUrl("http://www.inspiredluv.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/24-cool-wallpapers.jpg"
                    ,MyVolleyRequest(this@MainActivity).imageLoader)
            }
        }

    }
```